# trying to fix bug which gives conjecture the wrong number

Tags: numbering

I have a bug in some LaTeX code that I am working on whereby it gives a conjecture the wrong number. Here is a short piece of code which reproduces the problem, sorry if the code is a bit excessively long. In the code I give below the form the problem takes is that the conjecture appears as Conjecture 2.0.2 rather than Conjecture 2.0.1.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs,ulem,tikz, caption}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumerate,tikz,graphicx}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}

\textheight 20cm

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 7pt

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{theorem}[thm]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}

\begin{document}

\title{Poincar\'e Series and Zeta functions}
\author{Anton Deitmar,  Ming-Hsuan Kang, \& Rupert    
  M\MakeLowercase{c}Callum}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Gallery zeta functions}
\subsection{Zeta function of closed walks}

We summarize the above discussion as the following theorem.
\begin{theorem}

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete cocompact subgroup of $G$ and $\pi$ be the 
representation of the Hecke algebra $H(W,S)$ 

Then 
\end{theorem}

\section{Alternating products of Poincar\'{e} series}
Note that one can generalize the definition of straight strips to higher   
rank cases and study their stabilizers. We expect that there exists an 
analogue of Theorem [blank] for the cases of higher rank. More precisely, 

\begin{conj}
the following two identities holds.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $w_i$ is the generator of the stabilizer of some straight tube.
\item For any representation $\rho$ of $H_q(W,S)$, 
there exists certain ordering of 

such that their product under this ordering is equal to $W(\rho,u)$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{conj} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get Conjecture 2.0.1. in a current texlive and miktex.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using an older LaTeX kernel (pre 2015). In this case the counters associated to `subsection` don't reset when `section` is stepped. They do with LaTeX from version 2015/01/01.

The best is upgrading, of course. Otherwise you have to add the reset by hand, say with

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
```

and then, after the counter is defined, adding

```
\counterwithin*{thm}{section}
```

Here is code that examines the LaTeX kernel date and does the patch if its release date is before 2015; it does nothing otherwise.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{theorem}[thm]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}

%%% Patching code
\begingroup\makeatletter
\def\eky#1/#2/#3#4{%
  #1
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
}
\ifnum2015>\expandafter\eky\fmtversion
 {
  \usepackage{chngcntr}
  \counterwithin*{thm}{section}
  % add also other counters depending on subsection
 }
%%% end of patching code

\begin{document}

\section{Gallery zeta functions}
\subsection{Zeta function of closed walks}

Some text

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{Alternating products of Poincar\'{e} series}

Some text

\begin{conj}
A conjecture
\end{conj} 

\end{document}
```

[image]